# Jquery arrays not working

Tags: jquery

I need to have a tool that builds dynamic form elements. I wanted to build a multidimensional array to add the elements and then store the attributes of this element.

```
dType[100] = $('<input>').attr({'class':'inp'}),'type:input'; // 2 elements not working?
```

Trying to retreive via:

`dType[100][2]` to get the item needed, but not working.

```
      $('.addItem').click(function(){
          var dType =  [];
          dType[100] = $('<input>').attr({'class':'inp'}), 'dfdf';
          dType[200] = $('<textarea>').attr({'class':'inp', rows: 3, cols: 25});
          dType[300] = $('<select>').attr({'class':'inp'});
          dType[400] = $('<input  type="radio" value="one"><br><input name="rOptions" type="radio" value="two">');
          dType[500] = $('<input  type="checkbox" value="one"><br><input name="rOptions" type="checkbox" value="two">');
          alert(dType[900][2]);
          var dTypeNum = $(this).attr('id');
          var numDivs =  $('.InputItem').length; 
          var newNumDivs = new Number(numDivs + 1);
          var newDiv = 'inpDiv' + newNumDivs; 
          var newId = 'inp' + newNumDivs;
          var newElem = '#' + 'inpDiv' + newNumDivs; 
           $('<div>').attr({'id':newDiv, 'class':'InputItem'}).appendTo('.container');
           $('<label>').attr({id: 'tt'+ newNumDivs}).css('display','block').appendTo('#' + newDiv).text('Label');
           $(dType[dTypeNum][1]).attr({'id':newId, 'name': 'FD' + newNumDivs} ).appendTo('#' + newDiv);

             $(newElem).draggable( { containment: '.container',cursor: 'move',snap: '.container',stop: handleDragStop 
             });
```

Comment: (a) There is no such thing as "jQuery arrays". (b) `$('<input>').attr({'class':'inp'}),'type:input'` does not create an array (why do you think it does?).  (c) Arrays are 0-based. (d) [Learn more about arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Predefined_Core_Objects#Array_Object).

Comment: The first array level works fine dType[100]. I wanted to make it two levels so that I can store some attributes to make a hidden input also  that stores details that can be passed to SQL based on the input type. Each input type will have different elements and trying to keep code very simple and avoid a bunch of if/else statements.

Comment: What is `alert(dType[900][2]);`? I don't see that even set in your example.

Answer (score 2):

```
dType[100] = [$('<input>').attr({'class':'inp'}),'type:input'];

alert(dType[100]); //entire array at 100

alert(dType[100][0]); //first item

alert(dType[100][1]); //second item
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/M7UjS/2/

The jquery forum is a good resource: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/multidimensional-array

Answer (score 1):

This part of your script:

```
$('<input>').attr({'class':'inp'}),'type:input';
```

is two separate javascript statements"

```
$('<input>').attr({'class':'inp'})
```

and

```
'type:input'
```

so I don't really know what you're trying to do when you try to assign both to `dType[100]`.  The end result of the code you have is to only assign the first statement to the variable.

For a little less cryptic code that assigns the jQuery object to your variable, you would use this:

```
dType[100] = $('<input>').attr("class", "inp");
```

Then, if there were at least three DOM elements in the jQuery object, you could get the third object with this:

```
dType[100][2];
```

But, that would be undefined if there weren't at least 3 items in the jQuery object.

If, what you wanted was an array of two items assigned to dType[100], then you must put array brackets around it like this:

```
dType[100] = [$('<input>').attr({'class':'inp'}),'type:input'];
```

And, you could access the two pieces of that array with:

```
dType[100][0]
```

and

```
dType[100][1]
```

Comment: Thank you. I forgot that arrays start with 0.. My second piece 'type:input' is something I want to pass to the value of a hidden form element so that I can store in SQL and recreate later. It is always something simple.